# Call to undefined function pg_Connect() after enable php_pgsql.dll

Tags: php, postgresql

Call to undefined function `pg_connect` comes i am download the `php_pgsql.dll` file & upload it and configre the `php.ini` into `extension=php_pgsql.dll` before the same problem repeats.

Comment: Did you restart the server as well?

Comment: restarted xampp also but the same problem repeats .any help plz..

Comment: I would look at the Apache start-up logs. The module is not loaded. My guess is that the dll is incompatible with the PHP version, but the logs will tell you more.

Comment: Is any way to run dll file

Comment: hav any link for dll file

Comment: it depends. What php version, operating system do you have?

Comment: i am using php 5.6.3 win7 32bit

Comment: hmmm... did you try this: https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=44300

Comment: Great. Can you please mark the answer (added below for visibility for others) as accepted? Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try what is described in [this forum](http://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=44300).
The problem is also mentioned in [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.apache2.php#100918).